# How Hex is converted to binary before hashing sha256

Tags: cryptography, sha, converters

I know that string is converted to binary using its correspanding number in ASCII table, but what about Hexadecimal? It uses the binary representation of that number?
`0x0` is `0000`
`0x9` is `1001`
`0xF` is `1111` and so on?

Comment: Yes, that is how it's done. The actual programming details will be language specific.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a basic encoding / decoding question answered in the comments.